# What are the ideals of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What are the ideals of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1)$? I'm stuck at how to determine what ring this ring is isomorphic to?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*

- $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x^3+1) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x^3+1)$
- $x^3+1 = (x+1) (x^2+x+1)  \bmod 2$

Comment: I understand the first one, but why do you want to write $x^3+1$ in this way?

Comment: @shiyan, so that we can use the chinese remainder theorem.